# Special relativity radar doppler shift

Tags: special-relativity, waves, doppler-effect

Consider at stationnary radar at the origin $z=0$ and a target (speed $v$) moving along the $z$ axis and **away** from the radar. The radar is sending plane waves (frequency $f_i$) to the target and they come back to the radar (the radar is then both an emitter and a receiver).

I am interested in the **exact** expression of the frequency $f_r$ of the received wave (the one that bounces back off the target) viewed by the "receiver part" of the radar.

**Here is my attempt to the problem** (I did not learn special relativity) :

Because the radar is the observer (and not the moving target), I cannot make directly use of the  relativistic doppler shift formula. My goal then is to convert my situation into a source/moving-observer one.

Let's call the $\tau(t)$ the time taken for the emitted wave to go hit the target and come back to the radar. $\dfrac{\tau(t)}{2}$ is then the time taken for the wave to hit the target and is given by this equation : $$c \left(\dfrac{\tau(t)}{2}\right) = d(t) + v\left(\dfrac{\tau(t)}{2}\right)$$

where $c$ is the speed of light, $d(t) = d_0+vt$ the distance radar-target. We then find : $$\tau(t) = \dfrac{2d(t)}{c-v} = \dfrac{2d(0)}{c-v} + \dfrac{2vt}{c-v} $$

I now imagine a equivalent situation in which there is no more target but another radar moving with speed $v_r$ which is going to act like the receiver (recall that in the first situation, these two radars were considered as a single entity). The time taken by the emitted wave to hit the receiver is :

$$\tau(t) = \dfrac{d_r(t)}{c-v_r} = \dfrac{d_r(0)}{c-v_r} + \dfrac{vt}{c-v_r}$$

where $d_r(t)$ is the distance from the stationnary radar ($z=0$) to the receiving radar.

To make those two situations equivalent, I have to equate the two expressions for $\tau(t)$ :

$$\dfrac{2d(0)}{c-v} + \dfrac{2vt}{c-v} = \dfrac{d_r(0)}{c-v_r} + \dfrac{vt}{c-v_r}$$

I find

$$v_r = \dfrac{2cv}{c+v}$$

The frequency observed by the radar is then (by the relativistic doppler formula):

$$f_r = f_i \sqrt{\dfrac{1-v_r/c}{1+v_r/c}} = f_i\sqrt{\dfrac{(1 - \frac{2 v}{c + v})}{(1+\frac{2 v}{c + v})}} = f_i\sqrt{\dfrac{c - v}{c + 3 v}}$$

Is my reasoning correct? Did I forget to make use of special relativity when I calculated $\tau(t)$? Does the radar hear the same frequency in both situations? (in other words, is it sufficient to equate the two expressions for $\tau(t)$ to make the two situations equivalent from the receiver standpoint?).

Comment: "Because the radar is the observer (and not the moving target), I cannot make directly use of the relativistic doppler shift formula."  Well in Special Relativity, you can just transpose them - it's only dependent on relative velocity. Now if you want to incorporate gravitational doppler shift that's different - you would need to define the gravitational mass in the system.

Comment: @JMLCarter The radar is both the source and the observer. I don't see how I could transpose the situation 1) [stationnary radar (emitter+receiver) and moving target] into the situation 2) [stationnary radar(emitter) and moving radar(receiver)] by simply switching reference frame. What do I miss?

Comment: You original question seems to be about a stationary radar (tx&rx). When you change frame of reference to the target it becomes moving. This allows calculation of doppler shift observed by the target, which reflects light at that new shifted frequency, i.e. re-emits it. Move back into the frame of the radar and doppler shift it again to cover the return path. You get twice the effect. That is my suggestion, it is red shifted twice.( I'm not putting it in as an answer because I never did this particular scenario before.)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0998.pdf